# Why am I getting memory errors with valgrind? (C++, abstract syntax tree evaluation)

Tags: c++, valgrind, abstract-syntax-tree

I am currently doing an assignment for a course I'm doing. I have what seems to be a fully working program (I get the right output for all my test data), however when I run with valgrind it says that I have memory errors. Here is the minimal code to reproduce the error (which is still quite a bit sorry):

note: this assignment is about evaluating abstract syntax trees (not parsing, just evaluating)

header file: (provided by my tutor - I can't change this)

```
struct env {
  //will be used to store the values of variables in a stack. This is one 'node' of the stack
  string var;
  int value;
  env *next;
};

class Exp {
  //general expression - eval will be overridden.
 public:
  virtual int eval(env*) = 0;
};

class Constant : public Exp {
  int n;
 public:
  Constant(int n) {this->n = n; }
  int eval(env*);
};

class Var : public Exp {
  string name;
 public:
  Var(string s) { this->name = s; }
  int eval(env*);
};

class Let : public Exp {
  //let binding. (let bvar = bexp in body)
  //used to assign a value to variables
  string bvar;
  Exp *bexp;
  Exp *body;
 public:
  Let(string v, Exp *e, Exp *b)
    {
      bvar = v; bexp = e; body = b;
    }
  int eval(env*);
};
```

This is the code that I have written to evaluate this subset of the syntax:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "evalobj2.h"

int Constant::eval(env *env) {
  return this->n;
}

int Var::eval(env *env) {
  while(env) {
    if ((env->var).compare(this->name) == 0) return env->value;
    env = env->next;
  }
  //give up - variable not found in env
  throw 1;
}

int Let::eval(env *env) {
  //make a new struct env to be pushed to the environment stack
  struct env* newEnv = (struct env*)malloc(sizeof(struct env));

  //copy data into new env struct
  newEnv->var = this->bvar;
  newEnv->value = this->bexp->eval(env);

  //make it the head of the "environment" so that it is seen first when looking up a value
  newEnv->next = env; 

  //evaluate
  int valToReturn = this->body->eval(newEnv);
  free(newEnv);

  return valToReturn;
}
```

When I run the following from a main method I get "6 errors from 6 contexts" from valgrind:

```
Exp *e = new Let("x",new Constant(1),new Var("x"));
cout << e2->eval(nullptr) << endl;
```

Even though I get the right result. I have tested on bigger data structures with the rest of the syntax that I have to evaluate, all of which give correct results.

I don't understand what Valgrind is complaining about! It says "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised values" at "operator delete(void*)" .... by some other stuff that isn't mine... by Let::eval(env*) ... which is mine.

I will get 0 marks for a program with memory errors.

Comment: In addition to using `malloc` instead of `new[]`, your `Exp` class requires a virtual destructor.  If you attempted to deallocate the memory here using  `Exp *e = new Let(...) ... delete e;` -- the behavior is undefined.

Comment: *header file: (provided by my tutor - I can't change this)* -- Your tutor needs a tutor.  If you're supposed to dynamically create objects derived from `Exp` using a base class pointer, and (as should be required), deallocate the memory, your tutor's header file has a serious problem, as it cannot be done without introducing undefined behavior, with more than likely, that undefined behavior is a memory leak.  The reason is mentioned in my first comment above.  A grade of `F` for your tutor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct env {
  //will be used to store the values of variables in a stack. This is one 'node' of the stack
  string var;
  int value;
  env *next;
};

// ...

struct env* newEnv = (struct env*)malloc(sizeof(struct env));
```

You are allocating `env`, a structure with C++ classes, namely a `std::string`, using the C library's `malloc()`, which knows absolutely nothing about C++ classes.

This is undefined behavior. C++ classes must be allocated and destroyed with `new` and `delete`. It's surprising that your code survives long enough to produce any results, instead of crashing and burning, right from the get-go.

Answer (score 1):

you should use C++ memory allocation: for instance

```
int Let::eval(env *env) {
  //make a new struct env to be pushed to the environment stack
  env* newEnv = new env();

  //copy data into new env struct
  newEnv->var = this->bvar;

  ...

  int valToReturn = this->body->eval(newEnv);
  delete newEnv;

  return valToReturn;
}
```

Also, it's good practice to initialize data in constructors. At least:

```
struct env {
  env() : next(0) {}

  //will be used to store the values of variables in a stack. This is one 'node' of the stack
  string var;
  int value;
  env *next;
};
```